# Кэширование информации в java

Tags: java, кэширование

Разрабатываю серверную часть для мобильного приложения на java и для того чтобы много не обращаться к базе данных решил реализовать кэширование информации(сообщений , фотографий итд) , после написания простой реализации я понял, что кэширование обходится довольно дорого в плане ресурсов оперативной памяти. Какие есть эффективные способы кэширования информации, может есть готовые  библиотеки на java для этого?

Comment: Может гляните в сторону кеширования на уровне прикладного протокола? У `HTTP` Прекрасная реализация кеширования.

Comment: Евгений Иванов  я не сильно разбираюсь в кэшировании , то что вы сказали не вполне ясно для меня, можете описать более подробно?

Comment: В протоколе прикладного уровня `HTTP` для взаимодействия между клиентом-сервером, есть система кеширования, которая позволяет кешировать данные у ваших провайдеров, таким образом будет уходить меньше трафика, при этом каждое какое-то время проверяется были на сервере измения, если бы, стираем кеш, и запрашиваем данные. Примерно так. Могу описать подобнее в ответе, просто сейчас я с мобильного нет возможности.

Comment: Евгений Иванов если вас не затруднит, спасибо большое

Comment: Подключаете Ehcache, а потом мониторя статистику кэша через JMX, правите алгоритм до тех пор, пока не достигнете высоких показателей по хитам и низких по промахам.